# gphoto2. GPhoto2Error I/O in progress

Tags: python, camera, kivy

When I run the following code to choose the interested area for the second time, the app is crash and report the error. When I close the app or close the Image Window, the app is also crash. Someone says I need to pip install the opencv-contrib-python or add one more code line "cv2.waitKey(1)"  or add the code line "camera.exit()" to avoid it. But no effect. Here is my code for the take_image:

```
def on_mouse(self,event,x,y,flags,params):
    ...

def take_image(self):
    Clock.unschedule(self.update)
    file_path = self.camera.capture(gp.GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE)
    camera_file = self.camera.file_get(file_path.folder,file_path.name,gp.GP_FILE_TYPE_NORMAL)
    file_data = gp.check_result(gp.gp_file_get_data_and_size(camera_file))
    camera_image = io.BytesIO(file_data)
    camera_image.seek(0)
    image=cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(camera_image.read(),np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    self.image = cv2.flip(image, -1)
    cv2.imwrite(capture_path,self.image)
    self.window_name = str(time.time())
    print("Window_name=",self.window_name)
    cv2.namedWindow(self.window_name,cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
    print("I am here!")
    cv2.setMouseCallback(self.window_name,self.on_mouse,1)
    print("I am here again!")
    cv2.imshow(self.window_name,self.image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    self.camera.exit()
```

From the backend, when I call the take image for twice, it will print:

```
Capturing Image
Capture Image
Writing captured Image to /***/capture.jpg
Window_name = 1691574250.079184
I am here!
I am here again!
Capturing Image
Coverting captured image to Numpy
Writing captured image to /***/capture.jpg
Window_name = 1691574291.909509
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/***/app4.py", line 226, in capture App.camera.take_image()
  File "/home/***/cameraControl.py", line 177, in take_image file_path=self.camera.capture(gp.GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE) gphoto2.GPhoto2Error:[-110] I/O in progress
```